# IBM tone analyzer output in pandas frame has repeated values

Tags: python, pandas, ibm-watson

I am doing sentiment analysis for newsapi followed by tone analysis. I am able to display output of sentiment analysis and tone analyzer in pandas frame. The issue is that the output of IBM tone analyzer has repeated values. I would want that the values should be unique in each row. Here is code and output for the same:

```
from ibm_watson import ToneAnalyzerV3
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator

authenticator = IAMAuthenticator(apikey)
ta = ToneAnalyzerV3(version='2017-09-21', authenticator=authenticator)
ta.set_service_url(url)

result =[]
for i in new_df['description']:
   tone_analysis = ta.tone(
       {'text': i},
     #  'application/json'
   ).get_result()
   result.append(tone_analysis)
```

If I do `print(result)`, I get output as: `[{'document_tone': {'tones': [{'score': 0.677676, 'tone_id': 'analytical', 'tone_name': 'Analytical'}]}}`. Like this there are many values.

If I just type `result`, I get similar output but in different format as shown below:

[image]

It seems some issue using `result` and `print(result)`

Next I try to put values in pandas frame with the following code:

```
def f(x):
    x = ta.tone({'text': i}).get_result()['document_tone']['tones']
    return pd.Series(x[0])

new_df = new_df.join(new_df['description'].apply(f))
```

The output is repeated for the last three features i.e. "score", "tone_id", "tone-name", this is the issue. Moreover the repeated values are the last values which were obtained using  `print(result)` . The screen shot of output is given below:

[image]

Comment: What is `print (result[:3])` ? Is possible add completely ouput to question?

Comment: @jezrael I have edited the question, Please check. Thanks

Comment: Thank you, is possible convert picture to text?

Comment: Why not post [images of data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @jezrael.There is no dataset. I extract it through newsapi. I am sending you google colab link of entire code. Please check. Thanks:  https://colab.research.google.com/drive/17YVs617b4G3gjDDTpQ9h0fKJ6Ud7DsDm?usp=sharing

Comment: Sent request for permission.

Comment: same problem, `You need access`

Comment: @jezrael : Please check now, there's access granted.

Comment: Super, added solutio to your google colab, main problem was `def f(x)` instead `def f(i)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is multiple list of dictionaries per row, so answer is changed by flatten list comprehwension with `enumerate` for new columns names with numeric suffix:

```
#change f(x) to f(i)
def f(i):
    x = ta.tone({'text': i}).get_result()['document_tone']['tones']
    return pd.Series({f'{k}_{i}': v for i, y in enumerate(x) 
                      for k, v in y.items()}, dtype=object)

new_df = new_df['description'].apply(f)
print (new_df)
     score_0   tone_id_0 tone_name_0   score_1   tone_id_1 tone_name_1
0   0.677676  analytical  Analytical       NaN         NaN         NaN
1   0.620279  analytical  Analytical       NaN         NaN         NaN
2   0.683108     sadness     Sadness       NaN         NaN         NaN
3   0.920855  analytical  Analytical       NaN         NaN         NaN
4   0.825035   confident   Confident       NaN         NaN         NaN
5   0.632229         joy         Joy  0.527569   tentative   Tentative
6        NaN         NaN         NaN       NaN         NaN         NaN
7   0.574650     sadness     Sadness       NaN         NaN         NaN
8        NaN         NaN         NaN       NaN         NaN         NaN
9   0.751512   confident   Confident       NaN         NaN         NaN
10  0.618451   confident   Confident       NaN         NaN         NaN
11  0.672469  analytical  Analytical  0.912588   confident   Confident
12  0.764412   tentative   Tentative  0.840583  analytical  Analytical
13  0.660207   confident   Confident       NaN         NaN         NaN
14  0.840583  analytical  Analytical  0.764412   tentative   Tentative
15  0.786991   tentative   Tentative       NaN         NaN         NaN
16  0.753348     sadness     Sadness       NaN         NaN         NaN
17  0.672469  analytical  Analytical  0.912588   confident   Confident
18  0.590326     sadness     Sadness  0.877080   tentative   Tentative
19  0.560098  analytical  Analytical       NaN         NaN         NaN
```

For add to original:

```
new_df = new_df.join(new_df['description'].apply(f))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. Why in some rows we have    'NaN'.

Comment: @Akhter - because `ta.tone({'text': i}).get_result()` return empty dictionary, like `{}`

Comment: @Akhter - You think last one? Or how decide which is final?